# error on symbol lstat64, not defined in file libkernel32.so with link time reference

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, porting

I am porting an application to RHEL6.0 32-bit and gcc4.4.4. The build is successful; however, when running the application and try to navigate to another working directory (from inside my application), it crashes with this message:

```
my_app: symbol lstat64, version libkernel32.so not defined in file libkernel32.so with link time reference.
```

This happens with the debug build; there is no problem with the release build of my application.

Also, the debug build and the release build use the same "libkernel32.so"

When I issue the nm command:

```
nm libkernel32.so | grep stat64
```

the output is:

```
 U __fxstat64@@GLIBC_2.2
 U __lxstat64@@GLIBC_2.2
 U __xstat64@@GLIBC_2.2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use 32-bit library in the 64-bit code. Check you shared library and executable with nm or objdump. Both should be ELF-64 or ELF-32, but not mixed.

Comment: `symbollstat64`, version `libkernel32.so` doesn't seem right.

Comment: What OS are you porting _from_, and what helper libraries are you using?  "libkernel32.so" is not a standard component of any Linux distribution I am familiar with, but its name is suspiciously similar to the name of a standard component of Windows.

Comment: "lstat64" does _not_ refer to a 64-bit architecture, but only to 64-bit arguments of lstat (i.e. 64-bit file sizes and offsets)!

Comment: I'm porting from RHEL5.5 to RHEL6.0.

Comment: @Ctx you are right!